# Sorting an array by its key values

Tags: php, arrays, sorting

I am trying to sort an array by its value:

My array:

```
<pre>Array
(
   [1] => 11250
   [2] => 33750
   [3] => 56250
   [4] => 78750
   [5] => 101250
   [6] => 123750
   [7] => 146250
   [1.5] => 22500
   [2.5] => 45000
   [3.5] => 67500
   [4.5] => 90000
   [5.5] => 112500
   [6.5] => 135000
)
```

i want to reform it and it should be like:

```
<pre>Array
(
   [1] => 11250
   [1.5] => 22500
   [2] => 33750
   [2.5] => 45000
   [3] => 56250
   [3.5] => 67500
   [4] => 78750
   [4.5] => 90000
   [5] => 101250
   [5.5] => 112500
   [6] => 123750
   [6.5] => 135000
   [7] => 146250
)
```

I have tried ksort PHP function but it return only 1.I have tried other PHP funcions too but it is not working.
can any one guide me how can i achive it please?

Comment: What exactly are your keys? Floats? Strings? What exactly does "return only 1" mean?

Comment: my arry keys are floating numbers and decimal numbers only. and i am trying to sort array in ajax. as ksort function is not working in ajax.

Comment: this question is not duplicate and i have gone through other posts of SO and  not solving my problem..

Comment: Please show a more complete sample which illustrates the problem. It's unclear what exactly you're doing and what exact output you get.

Answer (score 2):

ksort is OK

```
<?php
$arr=array ("1" => 11250,"2" => 33750, "1.5" => 22500, "2.5" => 45000);
ksort($arr);
print_r($arr);
```

Demo - https://eval.in/742712

P.S. I've an idea that you try

```
$arr=ksort($arr);
```

This function is boolean so it returns true/false, not the array;

Comment: Probably that last paragraph is it…

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
ksort( $array, SORT_NUMERIC );
```

Answer (score -1):

For sorting array using key you can use PHP function `ksort()`

Comment: i have mentioned in my question i have already used it but not working.

Comment: You need to first ksort($array) and then only print $array, It will work.